# Unable to use Encrypted HDD on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS laptop

Tags: 14.04, windows, hard-drive, encryption

I've installed UBUNTU 14.04 LTS on an Intel 64bit system. I have a Western Digital External HDD that I use to transfer data from a Windows laptop to my Ubuntu Laptop with no problems.

Due to safety concerns about loosing my disks, I've encrypted my HDD in windows and now I can't see them in my File Manager when plugged to my UBUNTU Laptop. If I go to the Disk Utility I see the drive a s whole partition and can turn it off, but don't have much more actions to do.

I'll appreciate some advice since I'm an amateur UBUNTU user.